# not getting the option sqlite database from file in visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, visual-studio-2015, ado.net

What I have done:
- Installed the binary file of the provider on my machine from here 
     http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki
- Installed the following references in the project

- system.data.sqlite

  - system.data.sqlite.ef6
  - system.data.sqlite.core
  - system.data.sqlite.linq

Now when i try to do this 
add item --> Data --> ADO.net Entity data model --> efdesigner from database --> new connection --> change  in here I expect to see a "sqlite database file" option.

Comment: maybe it's a stupid suggestion, but have you tried reboot your machine?

Comment: I did a hundred times now..if that would solve the issue, I seriously think that we should avoid using this provider.
EDIT: I have done it now again, it is still the same

Comment: Any other help on this would be highly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 2):

This may help somebody else. There is only one binary file that is capable of installing the design-time components for Visual Studio 2015 ([system.data.sqlite.org](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki)).

[image: Editing Time SQLite version number]

Make sure to check "Install the designer components for Visual Studio 2015" during the installation process.

Once the installation process is done, restart Visual Studio and you will get the SQLite database provider installed.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by installing SQLite package marked as "This is the only setup package that is capable of installing the design-time components for Visual Studio 2015". After installing this, restart Visual Studio and you're good to go.